# syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

What am I doing wrong?  I think all my ends are right.  I am getting this error for

```
describe "visiting the edit page" do

describe "submitting to the update action" do

describe "visiting the user index" do

describe "as wrong user" do

FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com")}
```

and

```
describe "visiting Users#edit page" do
```

This is the error I am getting when I run rspec

```
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end


describe "authorization" do

    describe "for non-signed-in users" do
      let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}

      describe "when attempting to visit a protected page" do
        before do
          visit edit_user_path(user)
          fill_in "Email", with: user.email
          fill_in "Password", with: user.password
          click_button "Sign in"
        end

        describe "after signing in" do
          it "should render the desired protected page" do
            page.should have_selector('title', text: 'Edit user')
          end

          describe "when signing in again" do
            before do
              click_link "Sign out"
              click_link "Sign in"
              fill_in "Email", with: user.email
              fill_in "Password", with: user.password
              click_button "Sign in"
            end

            it "should render the default (profile) do
            page.should have_selector('title', text: user.name)
            end
          end
        end
      end

      describe "in the Users controller" do

        describe "visiting the edit page" do
          before {visit edit_user_path(user)}
          it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
          it {should have_selector('div.alert.alert-notice')}
        end

        describe "submitting to the update action" do
          before { put user_path(user)}
          specify {response.should redirect_to(signin_path)}
        end

        describe "visiting the user index" do
          before {visit users_path} 
          it {should have_selector{'title', text: 'Sign in'}}         
        end
      end
    end

    describe "as wrong user" do
      let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
      let(:wrong_user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com")}
      before { sign_in user}

      describe "visiting Users#edit page" do
        before {visit edit_user_path(wrong_user)}
        it {should_not have_selector('title', text: 'Edit user')}
      end

      describe "submitting a PUT request to the Users#update action" do
        before {put user_path(wrong_user)}
        specify {response.should redirect_to(root_path)}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing a `"` at the end of  `it "should render the default (profile) do`.

Answer (score 7):

Right off the bat

```
it "should render the default (profile) do
```

Is missing the end quote and be should be

```
it "should render the default (profile)" do
```

Answer (score 1):

I had in the podspec this character ” instead of this ".